# How can I change default laravel pagination css class to theme css class?

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to change my laravel pagination css to my theme css. How it is possible? can anyone help me with this?

here the theme css html

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col text-center">
        <div class="block-27">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
                <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my laravel pagination which is keeping its default css class.

```
{{ $projects->appends(request()->except('page'))->links() }}
```

I give the pictures also [image]
here you can see theme and default css.
I want to make lower one to upper one. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure to have pagination view ready in this way, depends on you to change it's default style**

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
  <ul class="pagination">
    {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
    @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
        <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    @else
        <li><a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
    @endif

    {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
    @foreach ($elements as $element)
        {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
        @if (is_string($element))
            <li class="disabled"><span>{{ $element }}</span></li>
        @endif

        {{-- Array Of Links --}}
        @if (is_array($element))
            @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                    <li class="active"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                @else
                    <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach

    {{-- Next Page Link --}}
    @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
        <li><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next">&raquo;</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    @endif
  </ul>
@endif
```

Place your view inside a folder and give it a name, then

```
 {{ $projects->appends(request()->except('page'))->links('view_folder.view_name') }}
```

I hope it will work